# Tornado's reverse_url to a fully qualified URL

Tags: python, tornado

Tornado's `reverse_url` is not a fully qualified URL. Is there a mechanism in Tornado to get back a fully qualified URL? For instance:

```
>>> some_method('foo', 1234)
http://localhost:8080/foo/1234
```

Comment: Why `reverse_url` doesn't suit your need?

Comment: Because I'd like a full URL. `reverse_url` in the above example provides `/foo/1234`

Comment: `'{}://{}{}'.format(self.request.protocol, self.request.host, self.reverse_url('foo', 1234))`

Comment: Thanks. That's ugly for something which seems like it should be very simple... :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a small helper method which I add to all my handlers:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin  # urlparse in Python 2

class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def reverse_full_url(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        host_url = "{protocol}://{host}".format(**vars(self.request))
        return urljoin(host_url, self.reverse_url(name, *args, **kwargs))
```